# Excel: Need a formula which can obtain a total amount of unique values in a range

Tags: excel, formula

Example: A10=111, A11=101, A12=111, A13=4, A14=101, A15=blank. The total is 3 unique values. I need a dynamic formula within a cell that can calculate all the unique values.  Blanks will be in the set range and should not be included in the total. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From Microsoft:

Count the number of unique text and number values in cells B2:B10 (which must not contain blank cells) (7)

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0),MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0))>0,1))
```

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-occurrences-of-values-or-unique-values-in-a-data-range-HP003056118.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in VBA: http://www.google.com/search?q=VBA+distinct

If you only need to do this one time, you can do it semi-manually in a couple steps:

1) Sort the values (say, in B10-B15)

2) In the next column, use this formula in each cell: `=IF(C10<>B9,C10,"")`. (Only show the value if it is not equal to the one above it.) That will give you the unique values.

By "total amount" do you mean a sum or count of distinct values? Either way, you can do that with the calculated column's values.

Answer (score 0):

You can Utilize this VBA code, The codes are well commented for you to understand.

`Sub sample_CntDist()`
`'`
`' Counting Distinct numbers, not counting blank values presenting count distinct in a cell Macro`
`'`
`'`
`Columns("A:A").Select 'select the column which have numbers`
`Selection.Copy 'copy the selection`
`Sheets("Sheet2").Select 'select a new sheet`
`Range("A1").Select 'select first cell`
`ActiveSheet.Paste 'paste the copied data`
`Application.CutCopyMode = False`
`ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$18").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo 'remove duplicates`
`Range("B1").Select 'select cell b1`
`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[-1],""<>"")" 'count distinct number excluding blanks`
`Sheets("Sheet1").Select 'select original sheet`
`Range("C2").Select 'select cell c2`
`Application.CutCopyMode = False`
`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "count distinct " 'give a caption for the result`
`Range("D2").Select 'select cell d2`
`Sheets("Sheet2").Select 'select the temp sheet`
`Selection.Copy 'copy the distinct count`
`Sheets("Sheet1").Select 'select and paste the result as values`
`Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _`
`:=False, Transpose:=False`
`Sheets("Sheet2").Select`
`ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False 'hide temp sheet`
`End Sub`